# Astro - Using client:load directive to include JavaScript for components not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, astrojs

I'm using React in Astro, and when including a TSX component and applying the client:load directive, it doesn't work, i.e., the JavaScript is not included.

I'm new to Astro.

This is how the code looks:

```
<Navbar client:load path="blog" />
```

I need interactivity for the Navbar because I have dropdowns and dropdown togglers. The onClick handlers on them are not working.

Comment: the way i built my website, is that i created an npm package for my Navbar then i have like 10 next.js ssg apps each with the navbar package installed in, now i want to use the same navbar on the astro app but for my blog i'm using it for my blog.

Comment: Do you have the `@astrojs/react` integration installed?

Comment: I solved the problem, I think the issue was that I was using a proxy server for development, and astro is generating scrips with / as base and it should be /proxy/port/route i.e /route returns 404.

Comment: Ahh, I see, in that case you need to set the `base` option inside the Astro config to `/proxy/port`. Glad you solved the problem!